# Template overload based on value of parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, enable-if

What I would like to do is to be able to have different declarations of the same template class, based on the value of a parameter, like this:

```
// Enable if X == 2
template <int X, int W, typename Y,
          typename A = int, typename B = int> struct Z {}; 

// Enable if X != 2
template <int X,        typename Y,
          typename A = int, typename B = int> struct Z {};
```

I could start with something like this:

```
template <int X, int W, typename Y, typename A = int, typename B = int, 
          typename = std::enable_if_t<X == 2>> struct Z {};
template <int X,        typename Y, typename A = int, typename B = int,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<X != 2>> struct Z {};
```

The problem with it is that, understandably, says that the it has been re-declared with a different number of parameters.

The variadic template feature could come in handy for this, but unfortunately, only supports types and not literals, as in this case.

```
template <typename... Args> struct Z {};
template <int X, int W, typename Y,
          typename A = int typename B = int> struct Z<X, W, Y> {};
```

> type/value mismatch -> expected a type, got 'X/W'

Has anyone have a solution for this?

**EDIT**

Sorry I didn't mention earlier, but unfortunately I cannot change the order of the parameters, since other parameters after `Y` have default values.

Comment: It sounds like an XY-problem. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You said you want to do as your comments here says:

```
// Enable if X == 2
template <int X, int W, typename Y, typename A=int, typename B=int> 
struct Z {}; 

// Enable if X != 2
template <int X,        typename Y, typename A=int, typename B=int> 
struct Z {};
```

*Apparently, you want to do without the second template parameter when `X !=2`. You could define it without a name.*

Partial specialization can be used to make the selection:

```
// PRIMARY TEMPLATE: Used if X != 2
template <int X, int, typename Y, typename A=int, typename B=int> 
                //^^ see here
struct Z {};

// PARTIAL SPECIALIZATION: Used if X == 2
template <int W, typename Y, typename A, typename B> 
struct Z<2, W, Y, A, B> {};
```

---

**EDIT 1 of 2:** *(as per your comment)*

> I want to be able to use the structure Z with only two parameters `(if X!=2)`: `Z<3, int>`

You will have to reorder your templates and use a default parameters in your primary template

```
// PRIMARY TEMPLATE: Used if X != 2
template <int X, typename Y, int=0, typename A=int, typename B=int> 
                             //^^ see here
struct Z {};

// PARTIAL SPECIALIZATION: Used if X == 2
template <typename Y, int W, typename A, typename B> 
struct Z<2, Y, W> {};
```

You can use as:

```
Z<2, int> z;
Z<3, int, 5> z3;
```

---

**EDIT 2 of 2:** *(to your Question Edit and comments)*

To paraphrase you:

> I want to be able to do `Z<3, int>` without reordering my template
>   parameters

You can only do something like `Z<3, int>` or `Z<2, int, ...>` if the second template parameter is a *type* **and** the remaining parameters are *defaulted*. Unfortunately, that's not your case. So you are at a dead end here, if this is really your problem.

Comment: Test your code, you have the wrong number of template arguments.

Comment: Nice, didn't know you could not name a parameter. But still, it doesn't solve the problem because I want to be able to use the structure Z with only two parameters (if `X!=2`): `Z<3, int>` gives an error. I would have to give something to be thrown out.

Comment: @Mehlins, in that case, you will have to reorder your template and use default arguments. See my updated answer

Comment: @Mehlins, I've seen your question update. And I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use C++14 and you can accept that your intergers are wrapped in a `std::integer_sequence`, you can define the two version of `Z` in this way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename, typename>
struct Z;

template <int W, typename T>
struct Z<std::integer_sequence<int, W>, T>
 { static constexpr int c { 0 }; };

template <int X, typename T>
struct Z<std::integer_sequence<int, 2, X>, T>
 { static constexpr int c { 2 }; };

int main()
 {
   Z<std::integer_sequence<int, 0>, long>     z0;
   Z<std::integer_sequence<int, 2, 7>, long>  z2;
   Z<std::integer_sequence<int, 2>, long>     zX;  // unacceptable ?

   std::cout << "z0: " << z0.c << std::endl;  // output: z0: 0
   std::cout << "z2: " << z2.c << std::endl;  // output: z2: 2
   std::cout << "zX: " << zX.c << std::endl;  // output: zX: 0
 }
```

I don't know how avoid a definition as `zX` with `X == 2` and without `W` but, if you want that `zX` works as `z2`, you can define `Z` in the following way

```
template <typename, typename>
struct Z;

template <typename T, int ... I>
struct Z<std::integer_sequence<int, I ...>, T>
 { static constexpr int c { 0 }; };

template <typename T, int ... I>
struct Z<std::integer_sequence<int, 2, I ...>, T>
 { static constexpr int c { 2 }; };
```

and `zX` return `2`.

The problem of the second solution is that are compiled even `Z` with an undefined numbers of integers. I mean that is compiled (with the second solution)

```
 Z<std::integer_sequence<int, 0, 5, 6, 7>, long>     z0;
```

**--- EDIT ---**

Sorry but I'm an idiot.

It's simple avoid the definition of `zX`.

In both cases you can declare (but not define) the following specialization.

```
template <typename T>
struct Z<std::integer_sequence<int, 2>, T>;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not possible without either reordering the parameters or using other data structures to wrap the parameters.

Anyway, you can use a `constexpr` constructor to submit the extra parameter and to be able to use your type in a constant expression.
As an example:

```
template <int X, typename Y, typename A = int, typename B = int>
struct Z {
    constexpr Z() {}
}; 

template <typename Y, typename A, typename B>
struct Z<2, Y, A, B> {
    constexpr Z(int W) { }
};

int main() {
    constexpr Z<0, void> z1;
    constexpr Z<2, void> z2{42};
}
```

If it's a good compromise mostly depends on the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the order of the template parameters, you can specialize your class and make use of default values :

```
// Chosen if X != 2
template<int X, typename Y, typename A = int, typename B = int, int = 0>
struct Z {}; // W is discarded

// Chosen if X == 2
template<typename Y, typename A, typename B, int W>
struct Z<2, Y, A, B, W> {};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1daf6fdfe1eb02a7)

Comment: Like I said in another reponse, it doesn't solve the problem because I want to be able to use the structure Z with only two parameters (if `X!=2`): `Z<3, int>` gives an error. I would have to give something to be thrown out.

Comment: @Mehlins Edited. By using default values, you can write stuff like `Z<3, int>`. You only need to reorder the parameters so that the defaulted ones appear at the end.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too, and sorry I didn't mention it in the post, but this is just a sample of the real structure, which is longer and more complex, and unfortunately I cannot change the order of things. In my case, `Y` and yet more parameters afterwards have default values.

Comment: @Mehlins Then put the real structure in your question. We can't work with what we don't have. That said, if your template has a lot of parameters, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @Mehlins Any reason why you can't reorder the parameters before those that are already defaulted ? The only rule you have to follow is putting every defaulted parameters after the non-defaulted ones.

Comment: Same reason as before. If I want to use `X!=2`, and define A or B, I would have to give something as junk. I also searched for any way to skip default parameters, but to no avail.

Comment: @Mehlins My bad. In your case, you need to have `W` as the last parameter. Do you also require the ability to declare a `Z` with `W` but without `A` or `B` ? For example, `Z<2, int, char, 4>`, where B should be defaulted as `int`.

Comment: Yeah. Basically `X` and `Y` need to always be defined. And in the case of `X==2` I want the user to define another parameter (`W`) as well. But it seems that it is not possible, I'll have to structure things another way perhaps.